# How do I tell if a list is in ascending order? Just needs to return True or False

Tags: python

The way I have it it stops after checking if the first two digits are ascending.

How do I make it keep running until it has checked the whole list?

```
def isAscending(xs):
    for n in range(len(xs) + 1):
        if xs[n] > xs[n+1]:
            return False
        else:
            if xs[n] < xs[n+1]:
                return True
```

Comment: Why does it need to check the whole list?

Comment: just remove the else clause and return True after the whole loop. You can also go for one-liner `all(l[i] <= l[i+1] for i in xrange(len(l)-1))`

Comment: get rid of the else: ... return True section.    Then outside the outer for loop return true.  If it makes it that far you can assume the list is ascending.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only return `True` at the end, that is after every element has been checked. Fixing your code with minimal changes:

```
def isAscending(xs):
    for n in range(len(xs) - 1):
        if xs[n] > xs[n+1]:
            return False
    return True

print isAscending([1,2,3,4]) # True
print isAscending([1,2,4,3]) # False
```

Short solution:

```
>>> lst = [1,2,3,4]
>>> sorted(lst) == lst
True
>>> lst = [1,2,4,3]
>>> sorted(lst) == lst
False
```

Better short solution that runs in O(n) (sorting is O(n log n)):

```
>>> lst = [1,2,3,4]
>>> all(x <= y for x,y in zip(lst, lst[1:]))
True
>>> lst = [1,2,4,3]
>>> all(x <= y for x,y in zip(lst, lst[1:]))
False
```

To make the last one more memory efficient, use `itertools.izip` in place of `zip` if you are using Python 2.

Comment: Wow. You came up with my exact solution (not accusing you!). Great minds think alike :)

Comment: @KaiChristensen The solutions are not the same. Yours  raises an `IndexError` for ascending lists.

Comment: oops. True, you added `len-1`

Answer (score 1):

Just keep track of the previous one:

```
def isAscending(xs):
    prev = None
    for n in xs:
        if prev is not None and n < prev:
            return False
        prev = n
    return True
```

Comment: and what is "n" here? you probably ment `prev = None`

Answer (score 1):

Use the Python built-in **all** operator to do the optimization and iteration for you.  The following code says "Let me know if *everything* in the list is **True**."  It will quit early if it finds a **False** value.

```
def isAscending(xs):
    return all([xs[n] <= xs[n+1] for n in range(len(xs)-1)])
```

For future reference, the **or** version of this is the **any** operator.

Answer (score 0):

Just have it return `True` if it isn't `False`! Whenever return is called, it breaks out of the function. Only one `return` is ever called.

```
def isAscending(xs):

    for n in range(len(xs) + 1):
        if xs[n] > xs[n+1]:
            return False
    return True
```

This way, if it is not in ascending order, then the function returns `False` and exits the function. If the `return False` is never activated, though, then the list must be in ascending order so the `return True` is activated.